# How To Get The Access of author and Display All of Them Using inheritance

Tags: c#

Hello i Searched a lot for accessing The attributes from the Child Class and Use it By The Parent Class But i did not found any info about that...
all i found is how to access attributes from parent class and use it by the object of the child class..
so is there any way to access the attributes of child class and use it by Object Of The Parent Class ??
Here is My Code..

```
class Document
{
    string titre;
    public Document(){}
    public Document(string titre) 
    {
        this.titre = titre;
    }
}
class Book : Document
{
    public string author;
        
    public Book() 
    { }
    public Book(string author) 
    {
        this.author= author;
    }
}
```

The problem is That i Cant Access The author value in that way below...

```
class Bibliotheque 
{
    List<Document> documents;
    public Bibliotheque() { }
    public Bibliotheque(int Capacite)
    {
        documents = new List<Document>(Capacite);
    }
    public void DisplayAllAuthorsInTheList()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < documents.Count; i++)
        {
            //i want something like that 
            //The error says that The Documents Don't Have The Definition Of Author 
            Console.WriteLine(documents[i].author);

            
        }
           
    }
}
```

in the mothod of DisplayAllAuthorsInTheList() the problem in documents[i].author its like The author is not accessed to be used with documents List
if you know how to access the author please tell me...
thanks Before..

Comment: In what way does this code fail?

Comment: in the mothod of DisplayAllAuthorsInTheList() the problem in documents[i].author its like The author is not accessed to be used with documents List

Comment: *"its like author is not accessed"* - Can you be more specific about the problem?  Are you getting an error message?  An unexpected result?  Something else?  I've copied your code to test it and it works as expected.  (Though I had to modify `Biblioteque` to allow actually adding a `Document`.)  What *specifically* is the problem?

Comment: The error says that The Documents Don't Have The Definition Of Author

Comment: i edited my code please look at it again

Comment: Well, `Document` *did* have a definition for `author`.  But a moment ago you edited your code to change that.  Now `Document` indeed does not have a definition for `author`.  (Why do you expect it to?)  It was working, so your first step would be to change it *back* to its working state.  Then determine what it is you want to change about the code and why.

Comment: the thing that i dont understand is why the Document does not have the definition of author even though i used Book : Document

Comment: Book : Document means that Book has all the characteristics of a Document, not the other way around.

Comment: *"why the Document does not have the definition of author"* - Look at your `Document` class.  There is nothing there called `author`.  The `Book` class has that field.  `Book` inherits from `Document`, so all Books are Documents in this code.  But not all Documents are Books.  Consider an analogy... All cars are vehicles.  Cars have engines.  Do all vehicles have engines?  No.  Bicycles for example do not have engines.  You're trying to access the engine on all vehicles, and the compiler is telling you they don't have one.

Comment: Thank You So Much You Corrected My Thoughts Now

Answer (score 2):

if you want the parent class to  use methods/attributes of child class you"ll probably need to use type casting but the variable needs to use the constructore of the ineriting son or else it will crash like:

Book book = new Document();

and the using casting u can use the child methods with the variable which is from the parent class like this:

string str = ((Document) book).author);

i advice to always check if the variable has an instance of the class you want to cast if you do this upword casting.